# Sails.js - how to save only model's fields into database?

Tags: javascript, sails.js, waterline

Let's say I have a model defined:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    username: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true
    }
  }
}
```

Then I create an object that I will save to database:

```
var obj = {
  username: 'blabla',
  score: 100,
  whatever: 'else'
}

Model.create(obj).then(...);
```

The additional fields will also be persisted into database. The question is - how do I save only the fields defined in model? In this case - username, even when trying to save all 3 fields.

I used to do it like:

```
Model.create({username: obj.username}).then(...);
```

But I wonder if there is a way to do this without having to map every field explicitly, because it's not very easy to maintain, and the model kinda loses its purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
schema: true
```

link to doc:

http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?schema

Comment: Added this to model config and it works nicely, thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to return an error if there are extra fields in the request, without resorting to manual input validation?